# Solving a differential equation using the contraction principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this simple initial value problem from a differential equations textbook I have.

[image]

Does solving the problem using the contraction principle simply mean showing that Picard's Theorem holds (as this is proven using the contraction principle), or is this asking for something more sophisticated?

Comment: It's debatable. However, the way I understand it, it is asking you to compute the solution as the limit of an iterative sequence. HINT: compute the solution via separation of variables (the result is $x(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$), then Taylor expand it around the origin. This might give an idea of what's happening.